# Send SMS to myself for free

Tags: sms, tasker

I'm testing a Tasker script that looks for a sequence inside a received SMS.

The problem is: who will send me this SMS ?

I could steal another phone and send me a text, but I'd be charged for the SMS'...

Is there an app for this, or even a shell terminal command ?

If the solution dispenses a computer, would be the ideal.

Tried this `https://www.opentextingonline.com/`, but I didn't receive anything.

Comment: You can try using Android Emulator and emulate receiving an SMS there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38897485. If your Tasker profile works in emulator, it should work on your phone too. Also,Tasker has a trial app on its website, so you can use it instead of going through the hassle of logging into Play Store, than downloading Tasker from there.

Comment: Thank you ! Just for the sake of curiosity, my spending consern was about the SMS. Rectified/elaborated my post.

Comment: Now, I'm just having some difficulty understanding the answers from the link you provided: which of them you believe is the most appropriate ? The OP seems to be looking for the same thing I do, but he points out that the provided answers are not adequate

Comment: One last thing: Instead of Android Emulator, is there a way I can use Terminal Emulator or something similar from within the phone ? Thank you again.

Comment: *"for free"* is misleading a bit, you still be 'charged' for sent sms (depending on your contract). are you asking for send sms via cmd line intent?

Comment: Thanks for the support. Well... All I need is to receive an SMS on my phone with a specific string. Nothing more. Now, who will send this SMS ? Another person ? A shell terminal ? Doesn't matter to me, as long as it's free and easy. :)

Comment: why don't you just send SMS to your own number? it works fine to me (at least with Textra) https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR1ZG.png

Comment: I'm starting to believe that is the only solution, alecxs. May I ask: was you charged by your carrier in your testings ? Mine charges, and I don't suppose the recipient will change that  :(

Comment: yes, of course. although it's a contract with unlimited sms flat, so i don't care

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64301613

Comment: Thank you again. That thread is promising. I left some comments on an answer there. Maybe you can respond them.